# Adding tables in jHtmlArea

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, wysiwyg, jhtmlarea

Anyone know of a way of making jHtmlArea support table content, and allow the user to add tables/cells/rows to the editor box? It doesn't appear to be a standard feature for the plugin.

I would like for my user to be able to create tables in the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Just change #editor to the "id" you set to the textarea.
and insert any styles if u have.Hope this helps.

[jhtmlarea wysiwyg editor - Adding Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205567/jhtmlarea-wysiwyg-editor-adding-table)